# Slang word 'BEOCH' pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, slang

I managed to find on Internet the meaning of the word BEOCH which equals BITCH.
But how is it pronounced left me wondering ! 
Could someone help me with, please .

Comment: BE•otch  ...long E, short O, accent on first syllable

Answer (score 2):

It's pronounced like Bee-Otch. First syllable the same as a "bee", second rhymes with "botch".

Let Jesse demonstrate (on 0:21):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVR476WHmR8

Comment: Thank you, Ronan, for the reference to the sound, on the 0:21 BEOCH is articulated exactly as is described in the answers,

Answer (score 1):

It is an alternative spelling for **biatch**. There is little or not much difference in pronunciation. Note that, since the stress is on the first syllable, the second syllable may be an intermediate sound between 'a' and 'o', perhaps a schwa.

Here is the definition (and pronunciation) from en.wiktionary.org

**biatch**

Pronunciation

(US) IPA(key): /bi.ˈɑtʃ/

Noun

biatch (plural biatches)

1.(pejorative, slang, gangsta) Alternative form of bitch

Quotation  Natika Waldon, Urban Affairs, page 197: “Fuck you, you son of a bitch!” Dana screamed, trying to cover herself. “Fuck your mamma, biatch!” he said as he kicked his door shut.

**Note (chasly)**

If the 'o' sound were to be pronounced fully then the pronunciation would be /bi.ˈotʃ/.

If you want to hear the word then my guess is that you need to listen to some gangsta rap. (never thought I'd recommend that to anybody!)

Comment: What do you mean by saying the pronunciation would be /bi.ˈotʃ/? I understood, and your answer seems to agree, that the "o" in this spelling is just being used to represent [ɑ], since that is the common pronunciation of that letter in American dialects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chasly, your is  a perfect answer giving me even more knowledge I have asked for !

Comment: This is just the disyllablization (is that a word? anyway, two-syllable version) of the Southern pronunciation of the word *bitch* with a diphthong [bɪjətʃ]. Also pronounced /bi.ˈʌtʃ/ and spelled with a "u" in multiple ways: See [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beeutch).